Ideal generated by $\langle x^2+y^2-1,y-x^2+1\rangle$
Let $K$ be a field. While doing an exercise I am trying to find the ideal $I:=\langle x^2+y^2-1,y-x^2+1\rangle$ in $K[x,y]$. I am guessing that the ideal is principal since otherwise the exercise would not make much sense. As a first step one can consider the relation from the second generator $y=x^2-1$ and we get
$$I = \langle x^2+(x^2-1)^2-1,y-x^2+1 \rangle = \langle x^4-x^2, y-x^2+1 \rangle $$
But now I do not see a way to simplify that any further.

The ideal is not principal.

why do you say the exercise wouldn't make much sense if the ideal wasn't principal?

@SassatelliGiulio And why is that?

@JackozeeHakkiuz I am asked to determine the scheme theoretic intersection of the two affine schemes $\mathrm{Spec}K[x,y]/\langle x^2+y^2-1 \rangle$
and $\mathrm{Spec}K[x,y]/\langle y-x^2+1 \rangle$ which is the quotient by the sum of the two given ideals. If it were not principal I thought there would be no point in calculating it.

@Flynn: why not? The quotient is much easier to work with than the ideal itself, since the second polynomial lets you get rid of $y$.

@FlynnFehre "And why is that?" because the ideal contains $y^2+y$ and $x^2+y^2-1$, but not $1$ (you prove that it doesn't contain $1$, if you care to do so).

This ideal is not principal as the intersection $\text{Spec}(K[x,y]/I)\cong\text{Spec}(K[x]/(x^4-x^2))$ is zero-dimensional, while a principal ideal in $\mathbb{A}^2$ should be of purely codimension 1.

Why is the intersection already $\mathrm{Spec}K[x]/(x^4-x^2)$? I mean, I am trying to calculate that intersection.

@FlynnFehre Consider the ring homomorphism $K[x]\hookrightarrow K[x,y]\rightarrow K[x,y]/I$. You can find that this is a surjective homomorphism with kernel $(x^4-x^2)$.
